# iOS:how can query the objects in nsmutablearray objects

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsobject

Can anybody help me to tell me how can access to objects in NSMutableArray.

This is how the creation of the objects is been made:

ViewController:

```
Students *studens =[[Students alloc] initWithDictionary:data]; //where data is NSDictionary
[self.studentData addObject:studens]; //where studentData is a NSMutableArray
```

in the Students is a NSObject class. in the Students class:

```
-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)studenDictionary
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.studentName= [stateDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
        self.studenLastName= [stateDictionary objectForKey:@"lastName"];
        self.StundenAddress= [stateDictionary objectForKey:@"address"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

if I nslog the nsmutablearray I'll get this output:

```
"<studens: 0x756b970>",
"<studens: 0xf46f9a0>"
```

my question for example how can I access the information of the student name John ?

Comment: Suggestion - rename your `Students` class to `Student` since each instance represents a single student.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use This to access:

```
for(Students *studens in self.studentData)
{
   NSLog(@"Name = %@",students.studentName);
   NSLog(@"LastName = %@",students.studenLastName);
   NSLog(@"Address = %@",students.StundenAddress);
   //or
   NSLog(@"%@",students);//if you have define description method in Students class...
}
```

If you want to print all local variables value all together as print for object you have to write description method in your Students class Like:

copy and paste this to your Students class...

```
-(NSString *) description
{
   return [NSString stringWithFormat@"Name = %@ \n Last Name= %@  \n Address = %@",self.studentName,self.studenLastName,self.StundenAddress];
}
```

Now if you `NSLog(@"%@",students);` it will show you all info.

Answer (score 3):

Implement the `description` method in your `Students` class:

```
- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Students: name: %@, lastName: %@, address: %@", self.studentName, self.studentLastNAme, self.studentAddress];
}
```

Now when you log the array, you will see useful information about each `Students` object in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html). It may solve your problem.
NSPredicates are queries which can be run on objects and are very helpful in functionalities like searching a particular object from array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Students *studenobj =[self.studentData objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@",studenobj. studentName)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if I nslog the nsmutablearray I'll get this output:
"<studens: 0x756b970>",
"<studens: 0xf46f9a0>"
```

As Your trying to Print Your Student Class Object that's why this you need to access the instance variables for your objects like this.

```
for(int i=0; i<[self.studentDataArray count]; i++)
{
    Students *studenobject =[self.studentDataArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"Name of Student = %@",studenobject.studentName);
    NSLog(@"Last Name of Student = %@",studenobject.studenLastName);
    NSLog(@"Address of Student = %@",studenobject.StundenAddress);

}
```